# matplotlib will not plot with button implementation

Tags: python, matplotlib

The below is part of a multi-thread program. The global variables adjustedTargetAskHistory and TimeStampHistory are updated from another part of the program and are flattened lists to appear on the y and x axis respectively. A callback allows the graph to update every 2 seconds.

I'm attempting to add implementation of a button on the graph. The function buttonPush() actually runs and prints the text. However, the graph does not plot.

```
def buttonPush(event):
    print("Pushed the button!")

def plotGraph():
    global adjustedTargetAskHistory
    global TimeStampHistory

    plt.ion()
    fig = plt.figure()
    axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
    plt.xlabel('Time')

    ax = plt.axes([0.0, 0.0, 0.2, 0.1])
    bcut = Button(ax,'Update', color='red', hovercolor='green')
    bcut.on_clicked(buttonPush)

    axes.set_autoscale_on(True)
    axes.autoscale_view(True,True,True)    

    adjustedTargetAskli, = plt.plot([], [], 'r-')

    while True:
        adjustedTargetAskli.set_data(TimeStampHistory,adjustedTargetAskHistory)
        axes.relim()
        axes.autoscale_view(True,True,True)
        plt.pause(2)
```

The problem appears to lie with the following lines as the plot will update seamlessly without them.

```
ax = plt.axes([0.0, 0.0, 0.2, 0.1])
bcut = Button(ax,'Update', color='red', hovercolor='green')
bcut.on_clicked(buttonPush)
```

Working (without button)
[image]

Not working (with button)
[image]

Comment: Reproducible example?

Comment: Images added to above

Comment: Well, I think it is `ax = plt.axes([0.0, 0.0, 0.2, 0.1])` ... you're updating on a new axis (because you plot via `plt`), which is probably somewhere behind your update button. What if you just replace that line with `axes.cla()` .. or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: `plt.plot([], [], 'r-')` did you mean to try to plot empty lists?

Comment: Yes @PaulH, it creates an empty array to initialise.

Comment: That seems to work @erocoar, I was thinking similiar. plt.cla(), followed by re-instating the axes axes = fig.add_subplot(111)

Comment: oh yeah, try to avoid most of the `plt` API. It's much better to operate on `Figure` and `Axes` objects directly

Comment: I would guess you mean `axes.plot([], [], 'r-')` instead of `plt.plot([], [], 'r-')`. Apart the code looks ok.